# Python jump back to def until valid input

Tags: python

I have the script where first the user is given a menu and then based on menu options the script runs.

```
def menu():
 descriptions = ('SetupFeeDescr', 'OveruseFeeDescr', 'RecurrFeeDescr', 'CancellationFeeDescr')
 planIds = input('Specify Plan Id. Multiple Ids seperated by comma: ')
 print('\n Which description would you like to update? \n')
 for i,j in enumerate(descriptions):
  print(i+1,"-",j)
 print("Q - Quit")
 user_input = input('Enter your selection: ')
 if user_input == '1':
    descr = descriptions[0]
 if user_input == '2':
    descr = descriptions[1]
 if user_input == '3':
    descr = descriptions[2]
 if user_input == '4':
    descr = descriptions[3]
 if user_input.lower() == 'q':
    return
 return(descr, planIds)
```

How do I make my 'main' loop forever until 'q' is given via menu?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 prefixes = get_prefix()
 descr, planIds = menu()
 data, old = get_plan_rates(planIds, prefixes, descr)
 replace_content(data, old, descr)
```

I don't think it's a duplicate of that other thread because I'm trying to loop over a definition indefinetly, and the script executes 4 defs.

Comment: Please use four spaces for indentation. One space is not very readable.

Comment: Two spaces is fine imo

Comment: I suggest 4 since thats what the pep8 specifies :) [Link to the pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make an infinite `while True` loop and ask user input inside. If the input is `"q"`, you call `break` and the loop ends. For you code it would be something like this:

```
while True:
    if user_input == '1':
        descr = descriptions[0]
    if user_input == '2':
        descr = descriptions[1]
    #....
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
```

**Note**: in each iteration you would overwrite the content of the `descr` variable. If you want to accumulate multiple choices, you have to use a data structure that can accomodate many values, like a list. This would then be:

```
descr = []
while True:
    if user_input == '1':
        descr.append(descriptions[0])
    if user_input == '2':
        descr.append(descriptions[1])
    #....
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
```

Then you pack everything into your `menu()` function, which at the end returns the `descr` list.

## Update

If you want to call the `menu()` function itself again and again until user inputs 'q', then you do it like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        if main() == "stop":
            break

def main():
    prefixes = get_prefix()
    result = menu()
    if result is None:
        return "stop"
    descr, planIds = result
    data, old = get_plan_rates(planIds, prefixes, descr)
    replace_content(data, old, descr)
```

Each time you call `menu()`, it returns either a pair of values, or, if the user input is "q", it returns `None`. Then you detect this condition and stop the script.

Comment: But that's only true if my entire program is running in menu() , but menu() is returning data passed onto 2 other definitions in 'main' so after 'replace_content' it should go back to 'menu' unless it's a 'q'

Comment: oh, I see, i misunderstood the question. wait...